# Safely remove an external drive makes Files crash

Tags: files, uninstall, usb-drive, nemo

when I use in Files (Nemo) the option 'Safely remove' for an external drive, the program always crashes (disappears completely). Some time later Ubuntu offers to send in a crash report.

Any suggestions?
Ubuntu 18.4

Comment: thank you, Gryu. I have done so each time.

Comment: If you wish, you can read the crash report. It's located in /var/crash/ and will happily display in any text editor (Gedit, Nano, Vim, Notepad, etc.) The report tends to be somewhat technical, of course, since it's intended to explain your crash to developers who didn't see it happen. If you can make sense of the crash report, it might provide clues on how to prevent the crash in the future. A crash is generally considered a bug, with a cause to be identified and fixed. It's usually not your fault, so there's often nothing you can do about it.

Comment: thank you, @user535733!

I cannot make much sense of the crash report. But these messages are, I think, from the crash moment:
apr 19 18:28:25 Henk-Asus-Ubuntu udisksd[1003]: Ignoring SCSI command SYNCHRONIZE CACHE failure (Non-GOOD SCSI status from SGIO v3 ioctl: status=2 host_status=0 driver_status=8) on /dev/sda
apr 19 18:28:25 Henk-Asus-Ubuntu udisksd[1003]: Ignoring SCSI command START STOP UNIT failure (Non-GOOD SCSI status from SGIO v3 ioctl: status=2 host_status=0 driver_status=8) on /dev/sda
...

Comment: apr 19 18:28:25 Henk-Asus-Ubuntu kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 1, async page read  
 apr 19 18:28:25 Henk-Asus-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[18967]: inotify_add_watch(9, /dev/sda1, 10) failed: No such file or directory    
apr 19 18:28:25 Henk-Asus-Ubuntu nemo[7591]: g_proxy_drive_poll_for_media_finish: assertion 'g_async_result_is_tagged (result, g_proxy_drive_poll_for_media)' failed  
 apr 19 18:28:25 Henk-Asus-Ubuntu udisksd[1003]: g_udev_device_get_sysfs_path: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed

Comment: apr 19 18:28:25 Henk-Asus-Ubuntu udisksd[1003]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed  
 apr 19 18:28:25 Henk-Asus-Ubuntu upowerd[1264]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.3/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0  
 apr 19 18:28:25 Henk-Asus-Ubuntu upowerd[1264]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.3/usb1/1-1